# Speeding up a mongodb find query with large documents

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongo collection of around 5GB that contains around 200k documents. Each of them has some name, a currency and a date and then a large string (which is the data I'm interested in), giving each document a total size of around 5MB.

My problem is that I need to find a certain name and currency for 250 different dates as quickly as possible.

Currently I'm using

```
db.collection.find(
{'name': somename, 'currency': mycurrency, 
'valuation_date': {'$in': [list_of_250_datetime_datetime]}
}) [see more detailed query in the update below]
```

Currently the speed is quite disappointing, as it seems to download only around 10 documents per second when I'm running the mongod server on my localhost.

I have also added indices for both name, currency and date, and also a composite index. Adding the indices makes it around 25% faster.

What else is there I can do to speed up loading these documents from mongodb?

Worth noting: the documents can't be split up as I need the large data string for each date/name/currency and I have no control over that part.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

Here a more detailed profile of what's happening:

Here the full query:
It sees to take around 94 secs with Pymongo for 916 entries, but around 6 secs for the first 100 entries with 3t studio.

`db.ForecastCurveId.find({
  'Ccy': 'USD', 'Class': 'ForecastCurveId',
  'Index': 'LIBOR', 'Tenor': '12M', 
  'source': {'$in': ['ods']},
  'valuation_date': {'$gte': new Date("2015-11-09"), '$lte': new Date("2016-11-07")}})`

[image]

here the profile if I use pymongo:
[image]

Comment: Are we talking of 250 specific dates? Sounds more like a range for me. Even if the dates are non-continous, I'd prefer to do a `gte minDate` and `lte maxDate` query with application level filtering than do a comparison of each and every data point in the collection with 250 values. Which would be 50M of comparison operations, with some additional 30k of logical AND operations further complicating issues.

Comment: My guess is besides inefficient indexing is that you also don't have enough RAM and disk speed to process the job. Each document is large (5MB), and I would hazard a guess that the server spent most of its time waiting for disk. What is the spec of your `localhost` server, and what MongoDB version are you running?

Comment: Mongodb 3.6 and I’m using and SSD on my localhost

Comment: @Nickpick RAM. Is it a dedicated server or are there other services (such as your application) running on it? And you did not answer my requests for clarification. That makes it hard to help, to say the least.

Comment: My local machine has 64GB Ram, 16 Core CPU. It also runs the application but it's not using any CPU.

Comment: Yes it's 250 specific dates, although a range would be possible, if the weekends could be filtered out. But would a range really be better? The dates are indexed, so it shouldn't really take time to look them up I would think.

Comment: Using a range doesn't seem to have any significant impact on speed

Comment: added more details and profiling info

Comment: Lets do the math. 916x5MB ~= 4.6GB. All of which need to be loaded and stuff. And god knows what pymongo does (there are smarter people around for answering this question). What you probably should do is not to load everything into a result set. But that is hard to tell without "da code". ;)

Comment: I need everything.